# Function with empty imput

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Is it possible to create a function in Rcpp of the following form

```
arma::mat functionName(arma::mat A, arma::mat B){
    
      if(input arma::mat B is empty){

     }else{

     }
 
}
```

So, if I call `functionName(A,)` should do what `if` points out and in the case where I call `functionName(A,B)` it should implement the `else` part.

Is that even possible when using Rcpp ??

Comment: Yes, look at the docs (and examples) for our `Nullable<>` class.  It's all a little tricky because R can only see an interface with a `SEXP` for its `.Call()` interface so we had to wrap it. But it does this very purpose just fine.

Comment: In particular, the very first function example at https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/optional-null-function-arguments/ demonstrates precisely what you want to do. Try compiling that function and calling `nullable1()` from R and you'll see it works.